# Search bar glitching out in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a search bar that displays results live. I've managed to do it properly utilizing SearchBar from 'react-native-elements'. Firstly I had it written as a class component, but decided to rewrite it as a functional component. After rewriting it I'm encountering a bug where the keyboard closes after one letter [as seen in the video here](https://youtu.be/uMJCo0LKdSM)

Here is the code of the component

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, TextInput, ListItem } from "react-native";
import { SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper'

import Header from "../navigation/Header";

export default function AktSelect() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [akt, setAkt] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://192.168.5.12:5000/aktprikaz", {
      method: "get"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setAkt(res));
  }, []);

  function renderSeparator() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  function searchItems(text) {
      const newData = akt.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.title.toUpperCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    setData(newData)
    setValue(text)
  }

  function renderHeader() {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="   Type Here...Key word"
        onChangeText={text => searchItems(text)}
        value={value}
        lightTheme={true}
      />
    );
  }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: "98%",
          alignSelf: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Header title='Pretraživanje aktivnosti' />
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text style={{ padding: 10 }}>{item.title} </Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <Text style={{ padding: 10 }}>{item.start_time} </Text>
            <Button style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignContent: 'flex-end', width:'30%'}} mode='contained' onPress={() => console.log('hi')}>hi</Button>
          </View>
          </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

The old class component can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/MislavPeric/0b28d8ad1990afe91ccb279879e92fff)